# Dynamic Refid is appended to the URL but i can't find refid in the response

Tags: jmeter

When i perform the action on UI a dynamic refid is appended to the URL using query string parameter. I can't find that refid in the response but its part of the request. In the code i only found the variable.
Here is the URL on UI.
https://XXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXX.com/Recruiter/#!/candidate/new/157072048
I captured the Get request for the same action using the developer tool on Chrome and it looks like this.
Request URL: https://XXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXX.com/Pages/candidate/new.aspx?refid=157072048&mode=quick
This Get request has 2 query string parameter.
refid: 157072048
mode: quick
Now i need to captured that refid and pass it the step 2 to be able to create that record. I need help to figure this out.
I found comment in the html that may be help full.

// `referenceid` - only used with the "Web" app, gets mapped to "&refid=123" in the query string, and ends up as Page.ReferenceID in WebForms.

Comment: Talk to your developers to see what APIs they are calling on the back-end.

Answer (score 0):

If this is not a part of a response data then it might be the case it's generated on the client by [JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/) code. You need to figure out how the value is being generated and replicate the same code using [JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/).

Another possibility is that the value comes from an [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) request which JMeter doesn't execute because it cannot execute client-side JavaScript. In this case you need to simulate the same request and extract the value from there.

And last but not the least, the number you're looking for may reside in one of the sub-samples which may appear as the result of [Redirection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) and you're trying to find it in main sampler response:

[image]